# Classic ASP Error Catching - Can it be done directly using an ASP.Net page?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic, vbscript, error-handling

Is it possible to catch ASP errors in ASP.Net (setup custom error pages in IIS) and somehow gain access to the Err oject or something similar like you would using server.GetLastError() in VBScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

not directly as far as i know, but you can have a classic asp error page that loads the err object values you need into different fields. then you could redirect to an asp.net page and that page will have access to the fields.

Comment: good idea. I have done something similar with javascript, sending a httprequest to the asp page for saving javascript errors to the database.